# KEIL error: no instance of overloaded function "std::transform" matches the argument list

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, arm, keil

I have a problem that does no resurface (even no warnings) in XCode but does allow me to compile in Keil MDK.

```
void grammar::parse(std::string &_expr) {
    std::transform(_expr.begin(), _expr.end(), _expr.begin(), std::tolower);
    _expr.erase(std::remove_if(_expr.begin(), _expr.end(), std::isspace), _expr.end());
}
```

That is what I get

error:  #304: no instance of overloaded function "std::transform" matches the argument list
error:  #304: no instance of function template "std::remove_if" matches the argument list

Header included:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
```

Could you please advise me on where to look? I am surprised that XCode version works as expected...

Answer (score 0):

You include `ctype.h`, that header declares a function `tolower` in the global namespace (this is part of the C library, so there are no other namespaces there). Maybe you meant to include `cctype`. For a given C standard library header `X.h`, there is a c++ version `cX` that provides some of the same functionality inside the `::std` namespace.

Comment: Thank you!I have replaced <ctype.h> with <cctype>, but that did not change the error. Should I have using namespace std;? could <iostream> cause error?

Comment: @AnnaShkodenko: The error might be a bit more confusing than what is really going on. If that did not solve the problem the issue might be (although the error message would not be really clarifying) that you are also including (most probably indirectly through `iostream` and potentially other standard headers) the `locale` header. There are some overloads of `std::tolower` in that header and the compiler might not be able to figure out which is the one you want to use. If this is the case, you could help it by *casting* (really selecting the overload): `static_cast<int (*)(int)>(std::tolower)`